# How can i insert the json data into different mysql tables?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the json file like below, i want the states to be entered first in state table, and the corresponding name that is the city should enter in another table and should take the id of the concerned state as the state id there are more than 1700 data. the sql structure should be

States table
id state

Cities table

id city state_id

where state id refers to the id of the state so that i can use joins.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mumbai",
        "state": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Delhi",
        "state": "Delhi"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Bengaluru",
        "state": "Karnataka"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Ahmedabad",
        "state": "Gujarat"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Hyderabad",
        "state": "Telangana"
    }
]
```

i have converted the json file into an array

```
$json = file_get_contents("resources/statelist.json");
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

how i can accomplish that? or any alternative as i am quite new to php..
note: there are many cities with same states the above json is just a part of full json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following

```
foreach($array as $row){
  $query = "INSERT INTO Cities values('".$row['id']."','".$row['city']."','".$row['state']."' )" ;
  $res = mysql_query($query);
 }
```